# Progress Ring (ellipse help) in C# / WPF

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a WPF application with an ellipse drawn. I am trying to make it so that it has one stroke, an aqua stroke, and another stroke, a darker blue one. I want the darker blue stroke to start from the middle and work its way clockwise, incrementally. Essentially a progress ring.

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bml1d.png)

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zzZu.png)

My code so far...

`<Ellipse Grid.Column="1" Fill="Transparent" Height="60" Width="60" Stroke="Aqua" StrokeThickness="2" Margin="21,17,369,123" />`

As you can see, I have the ellipse down. I just want to know how to add another border, which can be dynamically changed with a value. This is very simple in CSS, but I have trouble deploying it in C#.

Thank you.

Comment: Put both the ellipses in a Grid.

Comment: @Muzib What...?

Comment: Buuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuump! Someone plz help